# Get two strings into different labels after backgroundworker complete - vb.net

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, backgroundworker

Okay so i have spent times googling for some help or anything that may do the trick i want to do, but nothing helped. Anyway so i have this code

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork
        Dim Html As String
        Dim wc As New WebClient
        Html = wc.DownloadString("http://somesite/getusername.php?id=" & txtUname.Text)
        Dim mystring As String = Html

        Dim pattern1 As String = "(?<=<br>)(.*?)(?=<br>)"
        Dim pattern2 As String = "(?<=</br>)(.*)(?=<br>)"

        Dim m1 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(mystring, pattern1)
        Dim m2 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(mystring, pattern2)


        e.Result = txtLastKnown.Text = m1(0).ToString.Replace("*", "").Replace("Last", "")
        e.Result = txtPrevIps.Text = m2(0).ToString.Replace("IPs:", "").Replace("|", vbNewLine)
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bw.RunWorkerCompleted
        txtLastKnown.Text = e.Result
        txtPrevIps.Text = e.Result
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnResolve_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnResolve.Click
      Private Sub btnResolve_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnResolve.Click
        If Not bw.IsBusy Then

            bw.RunWorkerAsync()
        Else
            bw.CancelAsync()
        End If
    End Sub
```

what i'm trying to do is to get the `txtLastKnown.Text = m1(0).ToString.Replace("*", "").Replace("Last", "")` into the `txtLastKnown.Text` box and `e.Result = txtPrevIps.Text = m2(0).ToString.Replace("IPs:", "").Replace("|", vbNewLine)` into `txtPrevIps.Text` box after backgroundworker is completed but it's not returning anything? why? can anyone show me how i can do this correctly?

Thanks :)

p.s; i'm trying to get the output of `m1(0).ToString.Replace("*", "").Replace("Last", "")` and `m2(0).ToString.Replace("IPs:", "").Replace("|", vbNewLine)`
into two text box.

for example `txtPrevIps.Text` will output/show `77.775.766.79`
and `txtPrevIps.Text` will output/show 
`83.383.738.382
82.39.39.823
86.383.932.93`

so basically i want that `"77.775.766.79"` into `txtPrevIps.Text`
and `83.383.738.382
82.39.39.823
86.383.932.93` into `txtPrevIps.Text` after background worker is completed.

Comment: Did you try to escape `*` and `|`?

Comment: i guess you didn't get my question, more info added on what i'm trying to achieve.
[solved]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork

    '...

    e.Result = New String() { _
        m1(0).ToString.Replace("*", "").Replace("Last", ""), _
        m2(0).ToString.Replace("IPs:", "").Replace("|", vbNewLine) _
    }

End Sub

Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bw.RunWorkerCompleted
    If (Not e.Error Is Nothing) Then
        Throw e.Error
    End If
    Dim result As String() = DirectCast(e.Result, String())
    txtLastKnown.Text = result(0)
    txtPrevIps.Text = result(1)
End Sub
```